# EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null any suggestion please?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am facing this problem since I started to learn angular2.
news.service

```
    @Injectable()
    export class NewsServices {
    private news: News[] = [];

    constructor(private _http: Http) {}

    getSingleNews(id: string): Observable <SingleNews[]> {
        return this._http.get(`http://watania.info/getNewsById/${id}`)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }
    export interface SpecialNews {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    url_title: string;
    image: string;
    category: string;
    summary: string;
    date_to_publish: string;
    }
```

news.component.ts

```
    import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { NewsServices, SingleNews } from '../../services/news.services';

    import { News } from './../../services/news.services';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import { VideosPage } from './../../services/videos.service';

    @Component({
    selector: 'wn-single-news',
    templateUrl: './single-news.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./single-news.component.css']
    })
    export class SingleNewsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    sub: Subscription;
    private selectednews: SingleNews[]= [];
    private relatedNews: News[]= [];

    constructor(private _newsService: NewsServices,
            private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit (): void {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    let id = params['id'];
    this._newsService.getSingleNews(id).subscribe(
    selectednews => this.selectednews = selectednews);

    this._newsService.getRelatedNews(id).subscribe(
        relatedNews => this.relatedNews = relatedNews);
    });
    console.log(this.relatedNews[0])
    } 

    ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log(this.relatedNews[0])      
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
    }
```

The problem is that when I try to use any service like the above one, in any of my component like news component, I got undefined in the console for console.log(this.relatedNews[0]) in ngOnInit, but for console.log(this.relatedNews[0]) in ngOnDestroy I got the array. Moreover I can use the same variable in my template.

```
    <h1 class="news-header"><span></span> {{selectednews[0]?.title}}</h1>
```

It worked fine when use the variable in the template as shown above. but whenever I try to use it in the component I got

```
    EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    any suggestion please?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this._newsService.getRelatedNews(id).subscribe(
        relatedNews => this.relatedNews = relatedNews);
    });
```

is an async operation. You need to do your operations with `relatedNews` inside the callback(`subscribe`) like this:

```
this._newsService.getRelatedNews(id).subscribe(
        (relatedNews) => {
          this.relatedNews = relatedNews;
          console.log(this.relatedNews[0]);
    });
```

Comment: I tried it, the same thing happens. I got undefined. what frustrated me is why it give me the right result in ngDestroy and in the template but not in ngOnInit

Comment: @MohammedSabbah I don't think you did the same thing. The reason it is showing you the log inside `ngOnDestroy` is because in `ngOnDestroy` the `this.relatedNews` variable has enough time to be defined. I made a type in my answer before can you try it like the updated one.

Comment: Now it worked very well, thank you a lot. So, now for ever operation on related news I need to do the same thing? For example, if I need to use it like this this.metaService.setTitle('News page  '+this.relatednews[0].name); do I need to insert it like the console.log?

Comment: @MohammedSabbah yes because `getRelatedNews` is async you know, meaning it will happen but some time after. And that some time after part is inside the subscribe function. Check this answer for deeper understanding of how asynchronous functions work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323

Comment: Thank you very much you save my day :)

Comment: @MohammedSabbah glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Put your console.log(this.relatedNews[0]) inside the callback of your service like this:

```
 this._newsService.getRelatedNews(id).subscribe(
    relatedNews => this.relatedNews = relatedNews);
    console.log(this.relatedNews[0])
});
```

normally your console.log will return your object